# History back bug in turbolinks to a page with hash

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I'm having a little annoying problem with Turbolinks in rails, which I hope some of you can help me with.

I'm using jQuery-address to add hashes to my url in order to execute some javascript, when a specific hash value occurs.

The problem is that Turbolinks doesn't seem to work, if I click the back button (history back) and the history back refers to an URL with a hash. It simply doesn't change the page content. E.g. mypage.com/test2 and i go back to mypage.com/test1#1.

I want to make a js fix, so if I hit another page with a hash using history back, it should reload the page to refresh the content OR just force the content to refresh manually with Turbolinks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your JS?

Answer (score 0):

The best information I can give without code is that [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) refreshes the `<body>` of the page

---

**Delegation**

Normal HTML rendering is to re-render the *entire* page, meaning your JS is able to re-bind to the different elements. The way JS works is to bind an event to a specific element. That element has to be on the page (`document` / `DOM`) itself in order for the JS to bind to it.

Turbolinks is notorious for preventing JS from binding events to elements. As Turbolinks keeps the same JS on the page, it prevents binding for the JS.  Instead, you'll need to use the turbolinks [event handlers](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) to bind your events to the DOM, and delegate through turbolinks, like so:

```
var ready = function(){
    //your code here
};
$(document).on("page:load ready", ready);
```